# Encoding a JSON Array using PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to use PHP to return tName from the database and then output it in the following way: `{"tName":["Name1", "Name2"]})` So far it is returning `["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]` but that is not what I want.

Here is my current code

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT tName FROM Template");
$result = array();
while($e=mysql_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
$result[]=$e['tName'];
}       
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: `json_encode(array("tName" => $result))`?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add the key.

```
$result['tName'][]=$e['tName'];
```

or

```
json_encode(array("tName" => $result))
```